# How to handle database in a gem intended for system-wide command line tool

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I'm developing a gem that's basically used as a system-wide command line tool. This gem stores necessary data for the app in database. I'm wondering if there's any defacto-standard ish way to handle database in this situation.

So far, I'm thinking of using sqlite3 because I don't want users to go through these pain-in-the-ass processes to install system-wide mysql or postgress. (and yup, I'm using relational database and sqlite is more than enough in terms of performance etc, my app is just a simple small one)

If this is the right decision, the question boils down to where I should put sqlite3 database file. Definitely putting this under gem directory isn't a good idea, and so far I'm thinking of locating at /usr/local/MY_GEM/*.

Sorry the question might sound a bit vague for some people, but if I were to define a single question, it would be "Am I doing all right?" or "You guys have any better idea?".

Answer (score 0):

Is the database completely user specific?  Or is it static data your app needs?  If it's user specific I'd put it in ~/.my_gem.db or ~/.my_gem/data.sqlite3 or similar.

Comment: It is user specific, not thinking of network stuff and collecting data stuff etc.

And I didn't think of ~/.my_gem thing, and yea sounds like a good idea. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Philip's answer is great but you might also be interested in the XDG Base Directory Specification http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html I believe it is aimed at desktop applications but provides specification for data and config per user as well as system-wide configuration. High profile applications like Chrome and and Inkscape seem to make use of this specification.

The spec is based on environment variables but the result will likely be something like this:

```
 ~/.config/mygem/myconfig.db
 ~/.local/share/mygem/mydata.db
```